# Having trouble using power query to compare two excel csv's and showing differences (additions/deletions) between two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I have a daily task where I need to compare two .csv files that have data on users and which keysets they are assigned. On a daily basis people I receive the new .csv via email and check to see which users are added or removed and see which users had their keysets changed. Each file has around 1000 users on it. I have it set up where the two files are in a folder where the power query runs off of. It has been my first project with it so I'm seeing if it can be used for this.

I played with power query and was able to show the differences between the users of the lists. I imported and transformed the data, removed unnecessary columns, grouped the user column to count how many of each name was in that column, if two were found then they were unselected. This showed me the differences but lacked the comparison I am attempting to reach.

I plan on attempting other methods but am not experienced with all the things power query can do. I have made a test dataset to see if anyone has a good idea on how to have this report created

| Day 1 | Keys |
| --- | --- |
| Dave 1 | Key 1/ Key 2/ Key 3 |
| Dave 2 | Key 4/ Key 5 |
| Dave 3 | Key 1 |
| Dave 4 | Key 3/ Key 5 |

| Day 2 | Keys |
| --- | --- |
| Dave 2 | Key 1/ Key 5 |
| Dave 3 | Key 1 |
| Dave 4 | Key 3/ Key 5 |
| Dave 5 | Key 1 |

The results should show that Dave 1 was removed, Dave 5 was added, and Dave 2 had a key change and shows change in keys.

If anyone has an idea on how to create this please let me know or point me in a direction on where to find a result. I only have access to excel on my work computer so I am trying to find a way to use the software available rather than convincing the bosses to purchase anything new.

Comment: Things you could do:
1. convert user columns to lists and compare two lists (A,B).
   - if in A but not in B - deleted user
   - if in B but not in A - new user
   - if in A and B then - user that remained. For these users I would write a function that would compare keys and applied this function for every user. But it would require advanced level knowledge.
2. easier would be to read this from Power Query into two excel sheets and use excel formulas to achieve what you are after

Comment: As @SergeiZ points out, it is doable in Power Query. But an important consideration will be how to present the information once you've created your results.

Comment: The results will be generated in a similar way to how mark has created it below. I just need to show the changes to which I will copy and paste onto a separate spreadsheet. I'm sure there is an automated way to do so but I am fine with that aspect being a manual process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tutorialized Answer

This approach collects data from a folder called **Key Files** that contains a set of daily csv files. It summarizes every file in the folder into a normalized table of change events from one day to the next:

- Deleted - name has been deleted
- New - name has been added
- Key Added - name has a key added
- Key Removed - name has key removed
  The output table will contain four fields:
- Date - taken from the CSV
- Name - related to the event
- Event - calculated as defined above
- Key - if a key is added or removed, otherwise null

**Step 1 - Get files from folder**
Because you asked also how to get the data into Power Query, here is an illustration. You can research more techniques like this once you see how it is done and then go from there.  I put the csv files into a folder called **Key Files** within my **Documents** folder for illustration. I made three files so that the example is clear.
[image: files in folder]

For reference, the files contain the following data:

***keyfile0.csv***

| 15/10/2021 | Keys |
| --- | --- |
| Dave 0 | Key 2/ Key 3 |
| Dave 1 | Key 1/ Key 2/ Key 3 |
| Dave 2 | Key 4/ Key 5 |
| Dave 3 | Key 5 |
| Dave 4 | Key 3/ Key 5 |

***keyfile1.csv***

| 16/10/2021 | Keys |
| --- | --- |
| Dave 1 | Key 1/ Key 2/ Key 3 |
| Dave 2 | Key 4/ Key 5 |
| Dave 3 | Key 1 |
| Dave 4 | Key 3/ Key 5 |
| Dave 6 | Key 2/ Key 3 |

***keyfile2.csv***

| 17/10/2021 | Keys |
| --- | --- |
| Dave 2 | Key 1/ Key 5 |
| Dave 3 | Key 1 |
| Dave 4 | Key 3/ Key 5 |
| Dave 5 | Key 1 |
| Dave 6 | Key 3/ Key 5 |

To get these files, you need to **Get Data** >> "From Folder** from the **Data** tab as follows:
[image: get data]

My test folder path for this example is: `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Key Files`

You can also get file **From Text/CSV**, but if your two CSV files will have constantly changing names, you would need to modify your Power Query Script each time you run it. From the description in your comments, I think it would be easier to put all csv's into a folder and let the script adapt.

You will be given a window that looks like this:

[image: folder window]

You will want to choose **Combine & Transform Data**. After that, it will bring up a table based on the first file it sees and you can click **OK**. Now this needs an explanation - PQ created a script and a function to read all of the files in that folder and append them into a single table. This approach lets you eat all of the files at once and never worry about their names. The price you pay for this convenience is that you have to split these back into logical day values as you can see from this screenshot **Key Files** table:

[image: Key Files table]

Somehow, row 8 has to be matched against row 3 to see if Dave 1 changed keys and then you need to be able to detect that on 17 Oct, Dave 1 was deleted. At the same time, Dave 2 in row 14 needs to be compared to Dave 2 in row 9 and NOT in row 4. So you need some way of knowing the sequence of days. Either:

1. the filenames must be serialized in some order OR
2. your header Day 1, Day 2, etc. must have a serialized value like the actual dates.

I have chosen **2** because I cannot guess at how your filenames will be structured and 2 is harder to implement, so it is better for a tutorialized answer.  I will do that in the next step, so let's stop here and show the script that creates the **Key Files** table above:

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Key Files"),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File"))),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Table Column1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

**Step 2 - Transform the Key File Table**
As shown above, this step is required simply because of the choice above to read from a folder. If I were to do this in practice, instead of as a tutorial, I would streamline this, but instead, I will do it in separable steps. For illustration, I am going to create two tables from the **Key Files** table:

- **filedates** contains the file name and an associated date
- **nTable** is the normalized table that will be used in the final step to deliver the calculated outcomes.

To create these, right-click the **Key Files** table and select **Reference**.
[image: reference key files]
Do this twice. It will create two tables called **Key Files (2)** and **Key Files (3)**.
[image: rename]
Rename these to **filedates** and **nTable**.  Each of these must be transformed. I won't go into the details as that would make this a lot longer post, but here is the M script for each:

For **filedates** you just want to make a table of filenames and their dates. There are many ways to do that, but I just filtered for the work "Keys" because it computes fast.

```
let
    Source = #"Key Files",
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column2] = "Keys"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

For **nTable** you want to remove the "Keys" headers and then merge the result back with **filedates** so that you can have a serialized reference. As stated above, I chose to use the Date as the serial reference. I then split the Keys by row and renamed/removed columns.

```
let
    Source = #"Key Files",
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column2] <> "Keys")),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Filtered Rows", {"Source.Name"}, filedates, {"Source.Name"}, "filedates", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded filedates" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "filedates", {"Column1"}, {"filedates.Column1"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded filedates",{{"filedates.Column1", "Date"}, {"Column1", "Name"}, {"Column2", "Keys"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Source.Name"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {{"Keys", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("/ ", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Keys"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Keys", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Keys", Text.Trim, type text}})
in
    #"Trimmed Text"
```

The result of **nTable** looks like this:
[image: nTable]

**Step 3 - Calculating the Result**
So this is the answer to your question. Again, I will produce it as a separate step for illustration and modularity.

> NB: this is where Ron Rosenfeld said you could simply push this out and then do all the processing in Excel. The remaining steps are complex. I did not create PQ Functions because it would be harder to show and understand. This is more of a tutorial to see how you could do things. With more Power Query knowledge, you can modify this to suit your needs.

The following is the M script that takes in the **nTable** and produces a table I named **output**. You can go into Advanced Editor and paste this as a new source. Afterwards you can Close & Load To your Excel sheet to see the table results.

```
let
    Source = nTable,
    SortedNTable = Table.Sort(Source,{{"Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Keys", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}}),
    UniqueNameDates = Table.Distinct(SortedNTable, {"Name", "Date"}),
    CalculatedLatest = List.Max(SortedNTable[Date]), //
    CalculatedEarliest = List.Min(SortedNTable[Date]),
    NamesFirstSeen = Table.Group(SortedNTable, {"Name"}, {{"Date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    NamesAdded = Table.AddColumn(NamesFirstSeen, "Event", each "Added"),
    NamesLastSeen = Table.Group(SortedNTable, {"Name"}, {{"LSDate", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    NamesDeleted = Table.AddColumn(NamesLastSeen, "Event", each "Deleted"),
    AdjNamesDeleted = Table.AddColumn(NamesDeleted, "Date", each Date.AddDays([LSDate],1)), //names are  deleted on the day after last seen
    NameKeysFirstSeen = Table.Group(SortedNTable, {"Name", "Keys"}, {{"Date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    KeysAdded = Table.AddColumn(NameKeysFirstSeen, "Event", each "Key Added"),
    NameKeysLastSeen = Table.Group(SortedNTable, {"Name", "Keys"}, {{"LSDate", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable date}}),
    KeysDeleted = Table.AddColumn(NameKeysLastSeen, "Event", each "Key Deleted"),
    AdjKeysDeleted = Table.AddColumn(KeysDeleted, "Date", each Date.AddDays([LSDate],1)), //keys are  deleted on the day after last seen
   // bring it all together
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({NamesAdded, AdjNamesDeleted, KeysAdded, AdjKeysDeleted}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Appended Query",{"LSDate"}),
   //filter out first day adds and last day deletes
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each [Date] <> CalculatedEarliest or not Text.Contains([Event], "Added")),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Date] <> Date.AddDays(CalculatedLatest,1) or not Text.Contains([Event], "Deleted")),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Name", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Event", type text}, {"Keys", type text}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Name", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

The script above uses logical variable names in order to make the steps clear and it has some limited `// comments` inside.  Pasting it into the advanced editor (after you have done Steps 1 & 2) will let you see it more clearly and examine the **output** table at each step.

**Summary**

Here is the result based on the fake data I made above:

| Name | Date | Event | Keys |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dave 0 | 16/10/2021 | Deleted |  |
| Dave 0 | 16/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 3 |
| Dave 0 | 16/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 2 |
| Dave 1 | 17/10/2021 | Deleted |  |
| Dave 1 | 17/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 3 |
| Dave 1 | 17/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 2 |
| Dave 1 | 17/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 1 |
| Dave 2 | 17/10/2021 | Key Added | Key 1 |
| Dave 2 | 17/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 4 |
| Dave 3 | 16/10/2021 | Key Added | Key 1 |
| Dave 3 | 16/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 5 |
| Dave 5 | 17/10/2021 | Added |  |
| Dave 5 | 17/10/2021 | Key Added | Key 1 |
| Dave 6 | 16/10/2021 | Added |  |
| Dave 6 | 16/10/2021 | Key Added | Key 2 |
| Dave 6 | 16/10/2021 | Key Added | Key 3 |
| Dave 6 | 17/10/2021 | Key Deleted | Key 2 |
| Dave 6 | 17/10/2021 | Key Added | Key 5 |

So, as Ron pointed out in the comments, that last step is very involved. It delivers the events in a way that matches your criteria, but it may still not be exactly what you are looking for.  In any case, this 3 step approach allows you to dump all of the CSV files that you want to process into a single folder and then process all of them, no matter how large or how many there are.

> Here is the previous answer which is quite simplistic, but shows the basic idea.

### Basic Answer

To produce the M code in Power Query that mimics your situation, I am using Table1 as the Day1 table and Table2 as the Day2 table.  Assuming that you have ingested these into Power Query, the script could be:

```
let
     Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table2, {"Day 2"}, Table1, {"Day 1"}, "Table1", JoinKind.FullOuter),
     #"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table1", {"Day 1", "Keys"}, {"Table1.Day 1", "Table1.Keys"}),
     #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Table1", "Status", each if [Day 2] = null then "Deleted" else if [Table1.Day 1] = null then "New" else if [Keys] <> [Table1.Keys] then "Changed Keys" else null),
     #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Conditional Column", each ([Status] <> null)),
     #"Added Conditional Column1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Name", each if [Status] = "New" then [Day 2] else null),
     #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Added Conditional Column1",{"Name", "Table1.Day 1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Name"),
     #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"Name", "Status"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

This does a full outer join of the two tables, then it used a conditional column to determine if each row is either New, Deleted, Changed Keys or no change (*null*). It then filters out the no change and applies another conditional column to identify the New instances and copies the name from Day2. It merges that conditional column with the Table1.Day1 names to make a consolidated list of names. It removes the unnecessary columns and you are left with a normalized table of names and status.  I don't know how you want it presented, but with such a normalized table, you can either further shape it in Power Query or in Excel.

[image: result]

Comment: Nice initial presentation. I haven't tested your code, but it appears you are comparing the text strings in the [Keys] column. Especially since the OP also wants to know which keys have changed, it might be more robust to split the keys into a trimmed list for the comparison. Then no worries about order or extra trailing/leading spaces, and the changed keys are easily accessible.

Comment: This is a great representation. Thank you for your help with this. But my concern is that both my files are large and separate. Would I need to import each file to one excel sheet, and manually turn them into a table before I can run something like this? Also Ron does make a good point but I am not sure how difficult that will be.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld - you're right and I did not capture that requirement. That could be split and added as perhaps another output. Much depends on your original question in the comments: how should the output be structured?

Comment: Hi @Mickey - You could replace Table1 and Table2 with CSV imported tables. What I put in here is just for illustration. Also not Ron's question, if you state how you envision the output(s), then more specific M code can be created to give those results. Your task is completely achievable with Power Query, but some clarity on needed output would help. As for bringing in the CSV, Power Query will make quick work of that - look in Data>Get data>From file>Text/CSV. You can do that for each of your tables (files) of csv data and then do the merge and compare.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick Your original output for users looks great to be honest. The plan is to keep a running change log where your output will be copy/pasted into a running log so that all changes are reviewed over the life of the program. While I'm sure there is a method to auto fill that information to a list, I think that is very advanced for what I'm needing. If your output showed something like "Dave 2, Key 4 removed, Key 1 added" that would be optimal as it would show the exact changes that occurred. The output of the users is perfect.

Comment: Hi @Mickey - ok, I think I understand.  I can modify it, but will have to do it tomorrow AM (12 hrs from now). As for an autofill, there is way to do that with Excel 365, but it would require you to pull the data into worksheets first. The advantage (if I understand your intention) is that it would calc automatically, however, if you are importing that data from CSV, you would still have to Refresh, so there would be no benefit (unless you move all of this to Power BI Report Manager).

Comment: @markfitzpatrick This has been so helpful. I got the program to work perfectly and thank you for showing me how to do it. This has solved a problem I have been facing for a few months and you were able to fix it in a few hours. Thank you for your help Mark. I really appreciate that you shared your knowledge with me.

Comment: Sure @Mickey - I'm glad it helped. PQ is one of the most powerful tools in Excel. It delivers a lot of capability without a huge learning curve. As you learn more, I'm sure you will be able to apply it in many situations.